# Can I run a robocopy batch file from NAS1 to NAS2 without my local PC being on?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, nas

I'm copying files from my NAS1 drive to my NAS2 drive once a week. I've been using "NovaBackup", but sometimes it doesnt work correctly. I was wondering if its possible to run (see below) that batch and shut down my pc and it still run? I don't necessarily want to use /mir because I want to keep ALL files. Is that possible or any other idea that would be easier?

> ROBOCOPY \NAS1\reports \NAS2\backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Your PC will have to be on for `ROBOCOPY` to run.

Comment: Maybe the NAS device offers a way to backup to another location?